# How should I localize static ComboBox items?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have this very simple `ComboBox` with some `x:Static` items inside:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Source={x:Static u:Settings.All}, Path=CaptionFontStyle}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock FontStyle="{Binding .}" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    <x:Static Member="FontStyles.Normal"/>
    <x:Static Member="FontStyles.Italic"/>
    <x:Static Member="FontStyles.Oblique"/>
</ComboBox>
```

That gives me this:

[image: Normal] [image: Oblique]

It binds nicely to my `Settings`, the `FontStyle` can be applied to the items and I can use the `SelectedItem` directly without complications.

My problem is: How can I localize (translate) each item using a `DynamicResource` without losing the simplicity of this scheme?

I tried to derive from `StaticExtension` and simply add another string property to hold the localized text and link back to the control by binding:

```
<TextBlock FontStyle="{Binding .}" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
```

But this didn't work, as expected. :/

---

### *Post Responsum*

As @Funk wrote, I can simply use `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` to bind directly to a property of a class. So I'm currently using this scheme:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="FontStyle" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static u:Settings.All}, Path=MyFontStyle}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock FontStyle="{Binding FontStyle}" 
                       FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <TextBlock FontStyle="Normal" Text="Normal"/>
    <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="Itálico"/>
    <TextBlock FontStyle="Oblique" Text="Oblíquo"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a RichText class

```
public class RichText
{
    #region Text Property
    private String _text = "";
    public String Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; }
    }
    #endregion Name Property

    #region FontStyle Property
    private FontStyle _fontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
    public FontStyle FontStyle
    {
        get { return _fontStyle; }
        set { _fontStyle = value; }
    }
    #endregion FontStyle Property
}
```

And use SelectedValue to update Settings

```
<ComboBox 
    SelectedValuePath="FontStyle"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static u:Settings.All}, Path=CaptionFontStyle}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock FontStyle="{Binding FontStyle}" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <local:RichText Text="Foo">
        <local:RichText.FontStyle>
            <x:Static Member="FontStyles.Normal"/>
        </local:RichText.FontStyle>
    </local:RichText>
    <local:RichText Text="Bar">
        <local:RichText.FontStyle>
            <x:Static Member="FontStyles.Italic"/>
        </local:RichText.FontStyle>
    </local:RichText>
    <local:RichText Text="Far">
        <local:RichText.FontStyle>
            <x:Static Member="FontStyles.Oblique"/>
        </local:RichText.FontStyle>
    </local:RichText>
</ComboBox>
```

Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged when using Text Bindings.

Comment: I totally forgot about `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath`. This allows me to simply use a `TextBlock` instead of this custom class too. Thanks.